# I am looking for an application to test hybrid mobile application for android/IOS

Tags: automated-testing, android, ios

Any opensource application is available for to test hybrid application?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to ask here. Are you looking for a test framework like Appium that you can use to test Hybrid apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Manual Testing, you can use the emulators provided with the IDEs.

- [XCode Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) (iOS)
- [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html)
- There are online versions of both available online from services like BrowserStack.

For automation there are drivers for Selenium, JUnit tests in Android Studio, Unit tests in Xcode, or [Appium](http://appium.io/) (which uses the emulators from XCode and Android Studio and runs Selenium tests). If you go the automation route, Appium seems to be the most popular at this time.